# sd card access in android kitkat 4.4 issue

Tags: android, sd-card, android-4.4-kitkat

I have been able to find path of both internal and external sd cards on device.
Everything runs fine but only on devices prior to 4.4.

When I test the code on 4.4.x device I can't access a file I have to upload from external sd card.

How to solve this

Comment: The Android SDK does not have "internal and external sd cards". There is [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), there is [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and (to a much lesser extent) there is [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). The Android SDK did not have official access to removable storage before Android 4.4, and Android 4.4+ greatly limits what parts of removable storage you can access.

Comment: Post your code that does not work

Comment: @CommonsWare this means that my app will work fine in devices prior to 4.4.x while for devices above 4.4.x I have to restrict to internal storage only right?

Comment: Internal and external storage work fine on all Android versions. *Removable* storage is what changed.

Answer (score 0):

First identify which file you want from memory
then use like this.

---

```
        Intent pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
        pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
        pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, 0);
```

Comment: I dont want to use intent

Comment: Then you need to use content provider by which you can access data